# Why is data flow programming not the norm?

Tags: labview, dataflow

I wrote a simple genetic algorithm to evolve the string "helloworld". I wrote it twice. The first time was written using classes. And the second time was written using just functions where the entire state of the genetic world is passed from one function to the next...to mimic the data flow paradigm. Surprisingly, the code worked well for both the implementations. However, I managed to get it working only after painstakingly removing each and every bug, which was quite a laborious process.

And I asked myself.. there has got to be a better way. Write the code using classes was comparatively difficult than writing the same code using simple functions and I believe writing the same code visually, using something like labview for example would be a lot more easier than writing it only using simple functions.

To that extent, I read about data flow programming and visual programming and quite frankly it seems like it is more natural and intuitive to program in a visual, data oriented manner than in a statement-wise manner, which is what most programming languages enable us to do today. My question is.. if this is the case, why hasn't data flow, visual programming like "labview" become the standard?

Comment: There is no standard paradigm. There are many programming paradigms out there with languages that see very heavy use. The best paradigm is the one that best works for the problem you're attacking.

Comment: Also, just because something is harder to learn doesn't mean it's not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that data-flow / "Visual Programming" has nearly the performance of well-designed code.

Text-based code can express far more complex and subtle data structures and flows than anything graphical.   It gives programmers detailed control over what gets copied, what gets accessed, and precise control over sequences of steps.   I have a hard time seeing how data-flow could be that expressive.

Ultimately, data-flow /visual programming can only describe things that are already known.   Text-programming (for lack of a better term) actually lets you express more.  Programmers can create entirely new data structures and algorithms that simply haven't been represented visually yet.

Comment: I agree with what you have to say. But I think there still has to be a better way, where we can spend more time coding and less time debugging and I always thought programming in a visual flow based manner would help with that..

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to use a single problem as the basis for how programming languages should be designed. I'm not sure how the data-flow paradigm would improve GUI framework design, for instance.

Comment: +1 - Genetic algorithms are hardly day-to-day programming for the majority of developers.